# Problem with reading strings from File in C without string library

Tags: c, file

I'm experiencing a problem in the resolution of an exercise. I need to read N strings from file, but I can only read the first. How can I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main() {

 /* variable declarations */

   FILE *fp;
   char vet[100];


   fp = fopen("file.txt","r");  /* open file with N strings */

   while(!feof(fp)) {
     fgets(vet, 100, fp);
     vet[100]='\0';
     printf("%s\n", vet);  
   }

}
```

Comment: `char vet[100];` then `vet[100]='\0';` <-- Boom ! (arrays indexes start at 0)

Comment: Also you should make sure to call `fclose` when you're done with the file.

Comment: [Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Answer (score 2):

`vet[100]='\0'` this will generate error in runtime, also you don't need this line of code because fgets will handle the end of the string itself.

Comment: It's true! It woooork now! Thank's a lot!

Comment: @simonegolino you still may need to handle the `\n` that `fgets` adds at the end of the string.

Comment: @simonegolino _"this will generate error in runtime"_, no this statement is wrong. It triggers _undefined behaviour_ which is roughly anything between "program crashes instantly" and "apparently working fine".